# Safari randomly downloading files when visiting pages

Tags: macos, safari

I'm having a very weird issue where pages I visit will randomly trigger small file downloads from Safari (version 8.0.5) to my downloads folder.

The files are all very small, about 40-50 bytes. They have random names like:

- tr-2
- gif
- img;p=11042207125170;cache=
- blank.gif

I can't tell if this is an issue with Safari trying to save items to its cache or something possibly with a plugin or Extension. I've turned off all Extensions and it still happens.

Separately, I'm not holding the option key and clicking on any links or anything like that.

Any idea?

Comment: Well, you've turned off Safari Extensions, now disable plug-ins and see if that fixes it. Also, have you tried other browsers on the same machine?

Comment: Thanks for the help, that didn't seem to change anything.
 
However, disabling Javascript in Safari seems to temporarily prevent the issue. Obviously I can't really go without JS. Is there some way to change/modify/set the cache/download folder for Javascript? Or should I be worried that something is messing with my JS in Safari and this could be something worse than that?

Comment: You should definitely get to the bottom of this rather than trying to work around it.